# Необходимо в SQLite написать запрос и посчитать количество кодов разделённых #

Tags: sqlite, sqlite3

Существующая таблица. В диапазоне строк с одинаковым полем "cc" посчитать количество кодов - AU = , US = и т.д. [image: таблица]

Comment: вам нужно посчитать уникальные слова, или все?

Comment: @vp_arth В группе строк с одинаковым «сс» нужны количества всех видов слов. Скажем в двух строках с “сс=BR” AU=2, BR=1, CA=2, CN=2, EP=2, KR=1, MX=1, US=2, WO=2.

Comment: Здóрово, почитайте о нормализации. В таком виде это сделать будет непросто.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как мне известно, способа прямо подсчитать количество токенов по разделителю в `sqlite` нет.
Однако можно воспользоваться функциями `Length` и `Replace`:

```
SELECT cc, length(listOfCountries) - length(replace(listOfCountries, ' ', '')) + 1 FROM table;
```

Для поиска уникальных значений для `group by cc` вероятнее всего придётся нормализовать таблицу.

Comment: Нормализовать до какой формы?

Comment: До первой хотя-бы. Вам нужно завести таблицу со списком всех стран, и таблицу связей `cc <-> страна`. Так называемое отношение много-ко-многим. Нельзя хранить сериализованный список сущностей, если планируете осуществлять операции(подсчёт, группировка) с ними по отдельности

Comment: Нормализации я и опасался. Excel таблица, которая изображена, формировал не я. Я импортировал её в SQLite как есть, с кучей избыточности. То есть мне нужно создать правильную структуру с нормальными связями и справочниками. Затем из первичной таблицы перенести записи в новую. Скажите, так выйти из положения можно? Если да, то хотелось бы маленький пример.